# Can't login after reset of password in recover mode

Tags: boot, login, password, plymouth

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS :

I lost my password but found a way to reset it in this forum.

After restart I was not able to login and got a short black screen with some text. I recorded a video of the black screen and saw the following 2 error messages:

```
mountall: Plymouth command failed
mountall: Disconnected from Plymouth
```

How to do and fix?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the thread you used to reset your password, or explain the steps you followed ?

Comment: I used the following link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Comment: You could try to edit (press 'E' key) the line for booting with GRUB, then remove the 'splash' mention, then boot. Maybe that would help you ?

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't help. I Trier both removing the 'splash' aloen and also 'splash $vt_handoff'.